# How can we plot Man Ray's "Shakespearean Equation" w == e^(1/z)?

Tags: plotting, complex, generative-art

**1. Man Ray**

Man Ray (1890 - 1976) was an American artist who spent most of his career in Paris. He was a significant contributor to the Dada and Surrealist movements. Man Ray produced major works in a variety of media, including photography, but considered himself a painter above all.

[image]

*Man Ray in Hollywood, ca. 1948*

**2. His photos of mathematical objects**

In 1934 [Max Ernst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Ernst) suggested that Man Ray photograph the mathematical model collection at the [Institut Henri Poincaré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institut_Henri_Poincar%C3%A9). At the institute Man Ray encountered a *"dim hall, lined with glass cases containing hundreds of strange objects, covered with dust, objects in wood, plaster, paper-mache, metal, wire string, glass, glue, gelatin, paper."*

[image]

*Man Ray's photography of a Kuen surface, 1935*

Many of the models were German in origin, dating back to the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries. Man Ray ultimately photographed some thirty-four of the approximately three hundred models at the institute. Some of them he used as models for his paintings. More of Man Ray's mathematical works can be seen here (scroll down):

[Michael Whittle](https://www.michael-whittle.com/diagrams/the-shapes-numbers-make-and-the-problem-with-mathematics-the-diagrams-of-geometry-part-3)

**3. Reproduction with Mathematica**

Most of his object photos can be nicely reproduced with Mathematica, for example:

```
a = (u^2 * Sin[v]^2 + 1);
x = ((Sin[u] - Cos[u] * u) * Sin[v] * 2) / a;
y = ((Cos[u] + Sin[u] * u) * Sin[v] * 2) / a;
z = Log[Abs[Tan[v/2]]] + Cos[v] * 2 / a;

ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {u, -4.5, 4.5}, {v, 0.02, 3.12},
 Axes -> False,
 Background -> GrayLevel[0.2],
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
 Mesh -> 0,
 PlotPoints -> 40,
 PlotStyle -> 
  MaterialShading[<|"BaseColor" -> White, "RoughnessCoefficient" -> 0.5 |>],
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, 2.4, 1.}]
```

[image]

**4. Shakespeares Equation**

However, I couldn't replicate his photo of the following surface, which, according to an article in the *Notices of the American Mathematical Society*

[Man Ray's Human Equations](https://www.ams.org/notices/201510/rnoti-p1192.pdf),

"is based on the essential singularity in the graph of the real part of `w == e^(1/z)` at `z = 0`".

[image]

It served as template for Man Ray's oil painting shown below:

[image]

*Man Ray, Shakespearean Equation, Julius Caesar, 1948*

My trial with

```
n = 1;
ComplexPlot3D[Re[E^(1/z)], {z, -n - n I, n + n I},
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones",
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 Mesh -> 12]
```

[image]

didn't produce the expected result.

**5. Question**

How can I produce with Mathematica a faithful replica of the "Shakespearean Equation"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Need to use `Plot3D`.
- Need to cut some sigular parts near `z==0`.

```
Block[{w = x + I*y}, 
 Plot3D[Re[Exp[1/w]], {y, -.6, .6}, {x, -.2, .8}, 
  ColorFunction -> White, 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -.2, -.1, 0, .1, .2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
     5, 6, 7, 8}}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-5, 8}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #3 &}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> White, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}]]
```

- To find the proper region,we draw the `ContourPlot` with some curves which `Re[Exp[1/(x + I*y)]]==0`.

```
ContourPlot[Re[Exp[1/(x + I*y)]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, f}, f], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Cyan, ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image]

- Since `Re[Exp[1/(x + I*y)]] // ComplexExpand` is `E^(x/(x^2 + y^2)) Cos[y/(x^2 + y^2)]`, we finally find out that we need to remove the region enclose by the curves `y/(x^2 + y^2)` equal to `{2 π + π/2, -(2 π + π/2)}`.

```
ContourPlot[Re[Exp[1/(x + I*y)]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, y/(x^2 + y^2)], 
 Mesh -> {{2 π + π/2, -(2 π + π/2)}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Cyan, ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
Block[{w = x + I*y}, 
 Plot3D[Re[Exp[1/w]], {x, -.2, .8}, {y, -.6, .6}, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData["GrayTones"], 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -.2, -.1, 0, .1, .2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
     5, 6, 7, 8}}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-5, 8}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #3 &}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Gray, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, -(2 π + π/2) + 1/10 <= y/(x^2 + y^2) <= 
     2 π + π/2 - 1/10], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {-1, 1, 20}}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2.43, 1.23, 1.99}, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image]

- The above plot still missing two cylinder like regions in the center. We try to add them by using `Piecewise`

```
f[x_, y_] := Re[Exp[1/(x + I*y)]] // ComplexExpand;
plot = Plot3D[
  Piecewise[{{f[x, y], -(2 π + π/2) <= y/(x^2 + y^2) <= 
      2 π + π/2}, {0, 
     x <= 0 && ! ( -(2*2 π + π/2) <= y/(x^2 + y^2) <= 
         2*2 π + π/2)}}, Nothing], {x, -.2, .8}, {y, -.6, .6},
    ExclusionsStyle -> None, 
  Exclusions -> All, PlotStyle -> ColorData["GrayTones"], 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -.2, -.1, 0, .1, .2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
     5, 6, 7, 8}}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-5, 8}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #3 &}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Gray, 
  Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {-1, 1, 20}}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2.43, 1.23, 1.99}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

- To print to 3D, rescaling the region maybe useful.

```
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
TransformedRegion[reg, ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1/15}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I added `MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[z]],  Function[{x, y, z}, Arg[z]]}`, which is closer to the original mesh, but still not perfect